# Warning: Comparison between pointer and integer in while loop

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, int

I'm writing a program that asks the user to input the high and low temperatures over the course of three days. The high temperature for each day has to be greater than the low, the high must **not** be greater than 41 and the low must **not** be less than negative -41.

I wrote a `while` statement following the inputs for the first day however, I get the error comparison between pointer and integer.

I figured it had something to do with me using a set integer so I tried just making a `while` statement that involved high being greater than low, which resulted in the program working, but I found the while loop was skipped entirely. Here's my code so far:

**Edit:** I'm beginning to understand where my `while` loop went wrong. I believe it was because I neglected to assign a value from the array to the high and low and I also neglected to have the code rerun if the user met the conditions for the `while` loop. Initially, I had wrote it so the high and low held no value and the `while` condition was trapped in an infinite loop because I did not give it something to execute following the conditions being met.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 3

int main (void)

{
int high[NUMS];
int low[NUMS];
int max = 40;
int min = -40;

    printf ("---===IPC Temperatur Analyzer ===---\n");

    printf ("Enter the high value for day 1: ");
    scanf ("%d", &high);

    printf ("Enter the low value for day 1: ");
    scanf ("%d", &low);

     while (high[0] > max || low[0] > min || high[0] < low[0]) {
           printf("Try again\n");

           printf ("Enter the high value for day 1: ");
           scanf ("%d", &high[0]);

           printf ("Enter the low value for day 1: ");
           scanf ("%d", &low[0]);

    }

    printf ("Enter the high value for day 2: ");
    scanf ("%d", &high[1]);

    printf ("Enter the low value for day 2: ");
    scanf ("%d", &low[1]);

    printf ("Enter the high value for day 3: ");
    scanf ("%d", &high[2]);

    printf ("Enter the low value for day 3: ");
    scanf ("%d", &low[2]);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: high and low are arrays. They were decayed to pointer in that comparison

Comment: You need a variable to store the day number. Then change all the `scanf` values to use the day number as an index into your arrays: `scanf("%d", &high[day_num]);`

Comment: Use `high[0]` for day 1, `high[1]` for day 2, etc. For example, `scanf ("%d", &high[0]);` and `while (high[0] > max || ...)`. Your code would benefit from using a loop instead of repeating the same code for days 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Okay, I believe that by adding something like [0] beside high I am assigning it to a value in the array? I only recently learned about arrays, so I'm still trying to understand their functionality. Also, I implemented the above suggestions and managed to have the while statement work however, I am met with an infinite string of "Try again". How would I proceed in order to loop it in order to prevent this error?

Comment: If the values are not changed in while-loop, the condition will not change and the loop will be repeated. It is necessary to change the values(They should be re-entered.) in the loop.

Comment: Okay, so when the while condition is true, I added a line of code asking for the user to input the high and low for day 1 again and it's working now. The only problem I seem to be having now is that the while condition for low having to be greater than negative 41 is not registering. Is there something I have to do in order for the code to register a negative integer?

Comment: `low[0] > min` --> `low[0] < min`

Comment: The code as provided does compile without a warning on MSVC 2013. Please provide the code that produces the warning, not some similar code.

Comment: I fixed the code so there should be no errors in the text editor. The editor was just brining up an error because I had yet to attach a value from the array to the high and low for the second and third day. 

The problem I'm having though is that the negative integers are not registering. int min does not seem to have a value of -41 and if the user inputs a negative integer it does not seem to register either. There is no warning for this, but if you test the code it won't register the negative integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The high temperature for each day has to be greater than the low, the
>   high must not be greater than 41 and the low must not be less than
>   negative -41.

i have modified your code and written comment also to understand  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMS 3

int main (void)

{
int high[NUMS];
int low[NUMS];
const int MAX = 41;
const int MIN = -41;

    printf ("---===IPC Temperatur Analyzer ===---\n");

    printf ("Enter the high value for day 1: ");
    scanf ("%d", &high[0]);       //address of first element

    printf ("Enter the low value for day 1: ");
    scanf ("%d", &low[0]);        //address of first element

    /*Check for User Input Value*/
     while (high[0] > MAX || low[0] < MIN || high[0] < low[0]) {

           printf("Try again\n"); 

           printf ("Enter the high value for day 1: ");
           scanf ("%d", &high[0]);

           printf ("Enter the low value for day 1: ");
           scanf ("%d", &low[0]);


    }

    printf ("Enter the high value for day 2: ");
    scanf ("%d", &high[1]);

    printf ("Enter the low value for day 2: ");
    scanf ("%d", &low[1]);

    //TODO-:/*Check for User Input Value*/

    printf ("Enter the high value for day 3: ");
    scanf ("%d", &high[2]);

    printf ("Enter the low value for day 3: ");
    scanf ("%d", &low[2]);
    //TODO-:/*Check for User Input Value*/

    //TODO-:/*Print the all value*/

return 0;

}
```

Todo part you can complete by taking reference from other part of code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the high must not be greater than 41 and the low must not be less than -41. However, my only issue is with having the negative values register. It seems the const int of -41 does not register as a negative integer and the low value does not seem to register a negative input such as -15 either.

Comment: Okay, I see what my mistake was. I thought was supposed to be low[0] > MIN because MIN is -41, but it seems the program registers it the other way around. Thank you for the help Mohan.